# Henze-Zirkler Multivariate Normality on R and Python

Tags: r, python, normality-assumption, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am trying to run some ANCOVA analysis but beforehand, I would like to show that data follows multivariate normal distribution, which is one of the assumptions. On R, there is `MVN`package who does that which can be shown below:

```r
install.packages("MVN")
library(MVN)

data <- cbind(c(15, 19, 21, 27, 35, 39, 23, 38, 33, 50), c(20, 34, 
         28, 35, 42, 44, 46, 47, 40, 54), c(14, 20, 30, 32, 34, 42, 
         40, 38, 54, 56))
result <- mvn(data = data, mvnTest = "hz")
result$multivariateNormality
#            Test        HZ   p value MVN
# 1 Henze-Zirkler 0.5841257 0.2360863 YES
```

There is also Python equivalent, `.multivariate_normality` function in `Pingouin` library, which claims that the function is "Adapted to Python from a Matlab code by Antonio Trujillo-Ortiz and tested against the MVN R package."

https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.multivariate_normality.html

However, when I try to do the same Henze-Zirkler multivariate normality test on Python, it does not give me the same results:

```py
data_ = np.array([[15, 19, 21, 27, 35, 39, 23, 38, 33, 50], [20, 34, 28, 35, 42, 44, 46, 47, 40, 54], [14, 20, 30, 32, 34, 42, 40, 38, 54, 56]]).T
# (10, 3)

import pingouin as pg

pg.multivariate_normality(data_, alpha=.05)
# HZResults(hz=5.273295195237571, pval=1.9907293350099598e-20, normal=False)
```

To be honest, I did not type the equation of Henze-Zirkler test by hand because I just need to run this test as quickly as possible and I am a Python user, not R. There seems to be wrong with Python library doing this test or I am missing something out!